# Revolutionary slider quick fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, revolution-slider

I am using revolutionary slider for news page and news can have 1 or more than 1 image maximum of 6 images.

Issue i am facing is that i have to display more than 1 image then i used fade effect for transition but when i have only one image to show it loads with fade effect and it shows image with fadein effect. I dont want any fade effect i tried reduce time in milliseconds for different option but didnt manager to get ride of fade effect

My sample code is like this

```
<div class="banner-container">
    <div class="banner">
        <ul>
            <!-- SLIDE -->
            <li class="revolution-mch-1" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="100" data-title="Slide 1">
                <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                <asp:Image ID="imgTopBanner" runat="server" />
            </li>
            <!-- END SLIDE -->
        </ul>
        <div class="tp-bannertimer tp-bottom"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            revapi = jQuery('.tp-banner').revolution(
            {
                delay: 5000,
                startwidth: 1920,
                startheight: 700,
                hideThumbs: 0,
                hideTimerBar: "off",
                hideCaptionAtLimit: "",
                spinner: "spinner3",
                //dottedOverlay:"twoxtwo",
                //fullScreenOffsetContainer: "",
                navigationHAlign: "center",
                navigationHOffset: -430,
                navigationVOffset: 10, //340
                navigationVAlign: "top",
                //navigationType:"bullet",
                navigationArrows: "none",
                navigationStyle: "round"
                //navigationStyle:"preview4"
            });

        });
```

How can i take out fade effect today or avoid any transition over slides

Answer (score 0):

"How can i take out fade effect"...

Try removing the `data-transition="fade"` tag on slide elements?

Comment: That wont work i tried it bring in random transition not very smooth

Comment: data-transition="none"?